# Program took more time than expected error

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Below is a program to reverse a doubly linked list in gfg.

When I try to submit, I get the following error

> Your program took more time than expected. Time Limit Exceeded
> Expected Time Limit 0.00sec.

Can anyone tell me how to decrease my program's time?

**Code**

```
public static Node reverseDLL(Node  head)
{
   Node p,cur;
   p=head;
   cur=head.next;

   while(cur!=null)
   {
       if(cur.next==null)
       {
           p.next=cur.next;
           cur.next=head;
           head.prev=cur;
       
           head=cur;
           break;
       }
   
       p.next=cur.next;
       cur.next.prev=p;
   
       cur.next=head;
       head.prev=cur;
   
       head=cur;
       cur=p.next;
   }
   return head;

}
```

Comment: try posting at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How long does this take to run when you run it locally?

Comment: For completeness sake, you should add the `Node` class definition (although probably our guesses about its content might be correct). And a desrciption of your algorithm would be helpful, as your abbreviated variable naming degrades code readability.

Comment: for size 4 for it takes 18900 nano sec

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not correct:

The `prev` member of the (original) tail node is not set correctly. It is not set in the `if` block, but in the previous iteration, where it got its value with `cur.next.prev=p`, which is setting it to the (original) head node. This creates an infinite loop in the data structure. In the end, none of the `prev` links is `null`. It might be that the testing framework keeps following those `prev` links in circles until a time out happens.

Also, the function assumes that `head` is not `null`. This may not be guaranteed.

There are also too many assignments happening. With a doubly linked list it is quite simple: just swap the value of `next` and `prev` in every node:

```
public static Node reverseDLL(Node  head)
{
    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Node next = head.next;
    while (next != null) {
        head.next = head.prev;
        head.prev = next;
        head = next;
        next = head.next;
    }
    head.next = head.prev;
    head.prev = null;
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is classic solution for O(N) time, so I guess time constraint for this task is required to. solve it for O(1).
Take a look for this thread: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://discuss.codechef.com/t/reverse-a-doubly-linked-list-in-o-1/72850&ved=2ahUKEwjipdrQw_T1AhVYLTQIHahIDx8QFnoECBQQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1c0BDUotM0suEK7I4B9pQs